# How do I publish a Web Forms Application from VS2017 to IIS from Intranet?

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2017

I have developed an ASP.NET Web Forms Application in Visual Studio 2017(CE). It's the project that I've developed for my college, as an objective to run it as an Intranet Application so that it could run on a IIS on a PC and people can access it over the Intranet. I've tried using the Web Deploy method, generated a Folder and addressed the IIS to the Published files of Visual Studio. But I don't get it to work, and I feel it's not the right way.

I've tried some research but haven't been able to figure out the right context. Can anyone please recommend me the right place of instructions? Or instruct here itself?

Comment: What is the error you are seeing when you browse to your site ?

Comment: I don’t see the website. The website isn’t found.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to Solution Explorer and select the project then right-click the project
2. Click the Publish menu item then left panel to publish screen will be open like below screen
   [image]
3. Select the publish option as IIS, FTP, etc then click to publish button
4. The publish window will be open then select publish method as File System and type the Target location as http://localhost/Appname and click Next button.
5. Now, you can see the setting and file publishing options whatever you want to configure the options and click the Save button
6. Now you can find the application was published URL http://localhost/App in the output window

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Can that Application be used as an Intranet Website as well? I mean, if we try opening the website address on my mobile phone connected to the same internet as of my PC, will it work?

Comment: you want to deploy the intranet application or internet application. if you have deployed intranet application means it is not possible to use outside of the local network. but if you want to deploy the internet website (i.e. domain) mean you can access the application anywhere